# What is the heat kernel of the Laplacian on $U\subset\mathbf{R}^n$?

Tags: heat-equation, laplacian

I know that the heat kernel of
$$\Delta\colon C^\infty(\mathbf{R}^n)\to C^\infty(\mathbf{R}^n)$$
is given by
$$q(t,x,y)=(4\pi t)^{-n/2} e^{-(x-y)^2/4t},$$
but what about the heat kernel of
$$\Delta_U\colon C^\infty(U)\to C^\infty(U)$$
with $U\subset\mathbf{R}^n$? Is there an explicit formula? I've looked into some papers (e.g. [this](https://d-nb.info/1175165476/34) one), but all I found was that the heat kernel of $\Delta_U$ can be approximated by $q$ for small $t$.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel) says:
 "On a more general domain $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, such an explicit formula is not generally possible".

Comment: @Ali From the same article: "It is not difficult to derive a formal expression for the heat kernel on an arbitrary domain."

Comment: Do you have an idea what is meant?

Comment: Well the article goes on to describe a series

Comment: @Ali Now I understand - thank you!